# There should be a word or value in a dataframe, but everything is being displayed as NaN

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation, nan

I'm trying to merge 199 txt files into one that have the same columns. I was able to call them up and merge them, but when I try to merge the columns, all values become "NaN." There are 3 columns: Name, Gender, and Occurrence. How do I get the correct words/values to display?

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = 'data/names/' 
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)
print (all_files)
frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

df_a = pd.DataFrame(frame, columns = ['Name', 'Gender', 'Occurance'])
df_a
```

The output should have a name, a gender (either 'Female' or 'Male'), and a number associated with occurrence, not 'NaN' for everything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that all dataframes have the same columns, otherwise

> Columns outside the intersection will be filled with NaN values

(see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)